# CSS: Full width on specific

Tags: css

Hi I have a container which has a width of 1150px. Now I have this other mainmenu, with width: 100% that I want to place inside the container. But then ofcourse it only get 100%(1150px) but I want it full width from side to side, so it should ignore the setted width only for .mainmenu

I tried position: absolute which made it all wrong and weird

```
#mainmenu
{
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/mainmenu_bg5.jpg);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the menu in the container in the first place? If you want the menu to span the full width yet the contents of the container are only 1150px I think it is by definition not right to put the menu in the container. Consider restructuring your document. This is an example, I do not have your full code:

```
<body>
 <div id="page">
  <div id="header" style="background:Blue;">
   header header header
  </div>
  <div id="mainmenu" style="background:Green;">
   menu menu menu menu
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="width:1150px;margin:auto;background:Red;">
   container container container
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

And if you want the contents of the header and menu to span no farther than 1150px which I think is what you want then consider this:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.pagewidth {
  width: 1150px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="page">
  <div id="header" style="background:Blue;">
   <div class="pagewidth">
    header header header
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainmenu" style="background:Green;">
    <div class="pagewidth">
      menu menu menu menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container" class="pagewidth" style="background:Red;">
   container container container
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: While your solution might be "right" (in that it works) and might also be "correct" (in that there may be an error in the original document's semantics), I think it's wrongheaded to begin with to suggest that style decisions should dictate that something is wrong with a document's data design. There is almost always a better solution to conflicting styles and correct data than to alter the data.

Comment: Agree, perhaps my wording is not perfect (I'm not a native English speaker). I used the word "consider" to indicate reflecting on the possibility to justify a change in the document. If for any reason the change in the document is not justifiable then my answer might not be the best. however if a change is justifiable, for example when the site is not published yet, then my answer might be a good solution as it is easy to implement and to understand. I think it's better than fiddling around with contradicting css rules. It depends on the situation that Karem is in, imho.

Answer (score 0):

If your container is fixed-width, but you want a menu which has a background at full page-width, then you can have the menu background as a positioned background of `html`, and maintain the same HTML code. This will make the menu's background "bar" cover the whole page width.

Example of this method: http://templates.arcsin.se/demo/freshmade-software-website-template/index.html

How to do this: use positioned backgrounds:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Yes thats what i am looking for, making a menubar like that, how can i  have the menu background as positioned of html ? Can you show me an example, please check my updated question for css

Answer (score 0):

css is below, but sometime it depend from the content inside:

```
#mainmenu
{
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../images/mainmenu_bg5.jpg);
}
```

This is a jQuery solution:

```
$('#mainmenu').width() == $('#container').width();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a background image to simulate the menubar spanning the entire width of the page you need to apply the `#mainmenu` background to the `body` or a container div like so:

```
body {
    background: url(YOURIMAGE) repeat-x left 64px;
}
```

The `64px` needs to be how far the `#mainmenu` is from the top.

If the `body` already has a background image then you will need another div just inside the body containing everything else. If you have no control over the `HTML` then using javascript to insert a div that will either wrap all the content or get rendered behind it (using `position` and `z-index`.)

Answer (score 0):

position:absolute is the best way to get this *while keeping the background in #mainmenu*.  In fact, it's the only one I can think of off the top of my head.  Without javascript, of course.  Everything else will require changing HTML or moving the background property to a different place.

```
#mainmenu
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:??px;
    width:100%;
    height:37px;
    background-image: url(../images/mainmenu_bg5.jpg);
}
```

Because #mainmenu's width:100% then will become 100% of the viewport rather than the containing block.  (Unless a parent is position:relative or overflow:hidden)

So when you say it "got all weird", I assume that's because of other things on the page.  Both absolute and float take items out of the normal document flow.  So things below the menu can & will end up underneath it.

```
#mainmenu
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:??px;
    width:100%;
    height:37px;
    background-image: url(../images/mainmenu_bg5.jpg);
}
    #mainmenu + *
{
        padding-top:37px;
    }
    /* Exact selector not recommended due to poor browser support */
```

The solution to that is, basically, applying 37px of margin or padding to the first thing after #mainmenu.  You'll also be unable to center absolutely positioned elements using margin:0 auto, but if you want it spanning the full width of the viewport, that shouldn't be a concern...If you want to center the live sections of the menu, of course, you'll need some sort of descendant to center:

```
#mainmenu
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:??px;
    width:100%;
    height:37px;
    background-image: url(../images/mainmenu_bg5.jpg);
}
    #mainmenu > *
    {
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    /* Exact selector not recommended due to poor browser support */
    /* & more properties needed if descendant is list with floated <li>s */
    #mainmenu + *
    {
        padding-top:37px;
    }
    /* Exact selector not recommended due to poor browser support */
```

But there are lots of things you'll see change in relation to other things on the page with position:absolute.  So to troubleshoot that I really need to know more about the other things on the page.

You may find another solution, but if you don't -- post a page I can look at & I may be able to help you with the weirdness you experienced with absolute positioning.  That is, if it will work with this particular layout.